# Angular importing custom npm package gives "unexpected value" and @NgModule annotation error

Tags: angular, npm

I have an application that needs to be "part" of other applications. To do this I moved my components, services, interfaces, etc. to a library (published to AWS for private use). When I install the library into one my applications and attempt to use it I get:

```
ERROR in Unexpected value 'MyAppModule in D:/projects/my-project/node_modules/@my_appstore/my-app/my_appstore-my-app.d.ts' imported by the module 'SharedModule in D:/projects/my-project/src/app/shared/shared.module.ts'. Please add a @NgModule annotation.

Can't export value MyAppModule in D:/projects/my-project/node_modules/@my_appstore/my-app/my_appstore-my-app.d.ts from SharedModule in D:/projects/my-project/src/app/shared/shared.module.ts as it was neither declared nor imported!
```

I'm importing into my `shared.module.ts` file since that's handles global imports:

```
import { MyAppModule} from '@my_appstore/my-app';

    @NgModule({
      imports: [
        ...,
        MyAppModule
      ],
      declarations: [...],
      exports: [
        ...,
        MyAppModule
      ],
      entryComponents: [...]
    })
    export class SharedModule {}
```

I used `my-app`, `my_appstore`, as placeholders for the sake of the internet.

Not sure where the disconnect is.

Comment: Is the module actually exported in public-api in your lib?

Comment: @MikeOne Yes, I have `export * from './lib/my-app.module';` at the top of the folder which is the module in question.

Comment: You could try to specifically export the module instead of *.. I have had that issue in the past.. and we’re talking public-api file right?

Comment: @MikeOne correct, that export is from the public-api file.

Comment: @MikeOne switched it to `export { MyAppModule} from './lib/mya-app.module';` and still have the same issue. :/